# How to know if a QLineEdit got focus?

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit

I want to be able to know if in the `QLineEdit` it was a click. So I guess I should reimplement the following function(??):

```
void QLineEdit::focusInEvent ( QFocusEvent * e )   [virtual protected]
```

How should I do that?

Also, please tell me how to use `focusInEvent()` function in order to know if `QLineEdit myEdit;` object got focus.

**EDIT:** I have written the following function:

```
bool LoginDialog::eventFilter(QObject *target, QEvent *event)
{
    if (target == m_passwordLineEdit)
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::FocusIn)
        {
            if(checkCapsLock())
            {
                QMessageBox::about(this,"Caps Lock", "Your caps lock is ON!");

            }
            return true;

        }
    }
    return QDialog::eventFilter(target, event);
}
```

And have registered `m_passwordLineEdit` in `LoginDialog` class constructor like this:

```
m_passwordLineEdit->installEventFilter(this);
```

And it's falling into an infinite loop of MessageBox-es. Please help me to resolve this situation.  Actually I would like to implemet this function with a pop-up window (not with a `QMessageBox`). Is it OK to use `QLabel` for that need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like that:

```
class YourWidget : public QLineEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT

    protected:

    void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent* e);
};
```

In the `.cpp` file:

```
void YourWidget::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent* e)
{
    if (e->reason() == Qt::MouseFocusReason)
    {
      // The mouse trigerred the event
    }

    // You might also call the parent method.
    QLineEdit::focusInEvent(e);
}
```

You can find the list of all possible reasons [on this page](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qt.html#FocusReason-enum).

Comment: I wanted to implement with bool eventFilter(QObject *target, QEvent *event) in order to not write a Subclass. Have written the following code:
bool LoginDialog::eventFilter(QObject *target, QEvent *event)
{
    if (target == m_passwordLineEdit)
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::FocusIn)
        {
            if(checkCapsLock())
            {
                QMessageBox::about(this,"Caps Lock", "Your caps lock is ON!");

            }
            return true;

        }
    }
    return QDialog::eventFilter(target, event);
}

and I am falling into infinite loop of MessageBox-es. :(

Comment: That's because your `m_passwordLineEdit` will lose focus when a message box is shown and get focus again when this box is closed, resulting in showing the box again, ...

Comment: I would suggest showing some permanent message (eg below your line edit) when Caps Lock is on, even when it doesn't have focus.

Comment: @Narek: Job gave the correct explanation of the behavior you're confronted to. Add a permanent message (in a red `QLabel`) and display it or hide it depending on the status of the caps lock key. Beware that pressing caps lock while your `QLineEdit` is still focused won't trigger `focusInEvent()`. You'll have to handle that case too.

Answer (score 6):

> Also, please tell me how to use
>   focusInEvent() function in order to
>   know if QLineEdit myEdit; object got
>   focus.

You should connect yourself to the following SIGNAL :

```
void QApplication::focusChanged ( QWidget * old, QWidget * now )   [signal]
```

When the new QWidget is your QLineEdit, you know it got focus !

Hope it helps !

Comment: Ah didn't know that signal. This is very useful because you don't have to inherit a widget just to override `focusInEvent`! The downside is that you have to react on *every* focus change in your application. Still worth a +1

Comment: This is an overkill. Should be a better approach I think. Any way thanks.

Comment: how would that be done in Python ? I do  not want to build a custom class for Filters and then install that as `QLineEdit.installEventFilter(CustomeFilterClass)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know when someone clicks in a widget, you should override `mousePressEvent (QMouseEvent* event)`. A `focusInEvent` can be triggered by other sources than a mouse click.

For example:

```
class MyLineEdit : public QLineEdit
{
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        //...
    protected:
         void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
         {
              //pass the event to QLineEdit
              QLineEdit::mousePressEvent(event);
              //register the click or act on it
         }
};
```

If you do want to know when your widget receives focus, do the same with a `focusInEvent` of course.

Comment: If he wants to know if the click focused the widget, doing so is unsafe.

Comment: "unsafe" might indeed be too much ;) I meant that some widget might trigger a mousePressEvent() but still not get the focus. But you got my point.