# How to get Click Event of QLineEdit in Qt?

Tags: qt

How to get Click Event of `QLineEdit` in Qt ?

I am not able to see any SLOT related to click in `QLineEdit` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to reimplement **focusInEvent** in a new class extending QLineEdit. The following links are going to help you.

1. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusInEvent
2. [QLineEdit - focus event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804115/qlineedit-focus-event)
3. [How to know if a QLineEdit got focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012351/how-to-know-if-a-qlineedit-got-focus)
4. [QLineEdit Focus Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869505/qlineedit-focus-event)

Answer (score 29):

I don't think subclassing a QLineEdit is the right choice.  Why subclass if you don't need to?  You could instead use event filters.  Check out [QObject::eventFilter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter).

Example:

```
MyClass::MyClass() :
    edit(new QLineEdit(this))
{
    edit->installEventFilter(this);
}

bool MyClass::eventFilter(QObject* object, QEvent* event)
{
    if(object == edit && event->type() == QEvent::FocusIn) {
        // bring up your custom edit
        return false; // lets the event continue to the edit
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: looks like `QEvent::FocusIn` is more appropriate type here.

Comment: there is no `QEvent::MouseClick` event. Use `QEvent::MouseButtonPres` instead

Answer (score 3):

Although there is no "clicked" or "entered" event. You can use the

```
void cursorPositionChanged(int old, int new)
```

[Signal](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#signals). It is emitted when the user clicks the lineedit (if it is enabled) and also on a few other occasions so you have to verify which of the events actually happened but I think this is still easier than subclassing or using the event listener for some applications.

Comment: You will get a lot of these signals, and not just for clicking inside the QLineEdit!

Comment: get these events just creating the object even when there is no cursor activity by the user

Answer (score 2):

I dono if this will help, 
i had to call a function once a text is entered. This is how i did it.

```
connect(ui->passwordSetLineEdit,SIGNAL(textEdited(QString)),this,SLOT(onTextEdit(QString)));
```

when a text is entered textEdited signal will be emited, thus my onTextEdit function will be called.

Answer (score 1):

There is no signals like `clicked()` for `QLineEdit`, but you can subclass it and emit such signal in your custom implementation of `mouseReleaseEvent`.

Answer (score 1):

In PyQT you can do something like this:

```
self.lineEdit_passwort.mousePressEvent = self.on_lineEdit_passwort_clicked

def on_lineEdit_passwort_clicked(self, *arg, **kwargs):
    print("lineEdit_passwort clicked!")
```

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I used this solution many times

```
def clickable(widget): # make this function global
    class Filter(QObject):
        clicked = pyqtSignal()

        def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
            if obj == widget and event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonRelease and obj.rect().contains(event.pos()):
                self.clicked.emit()
                return True
            else:
                return False
    filter = Filter(widget)
    widget.installEventFilter(filter)
    return filter.clicked

clickable(self.lineedit).connect(self.test) #use this in class

def test(self):
    print("lineedit pressed")
    pass
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Just use the Pushbutton clicked event. Change the backcolor of the Pushbutton into Transparent then remove the text of it. Lay it in front of the LineEdit then use the setfocus property of the LineEdit when the push button was clicked. That's the easiest way to get the clicked event and use it in LineEdit..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).