# How to store the name of QlineEdit in a variable when its clicked?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

There is no signal as clicked for QlineEdit.

```
connect(w,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT());
```

Comment: Have you looked at [`focusInEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#focusInEvent)?

Comment: how does that work?Can u please elaborate i am amateur.

Comment: Concerning `focusInEvent`, see [Event System](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html) for more information. An alternative is to use the [`textEdited`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#textEdited) or [`textChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#textChanged) signals depending on what you really want.

Comment: lets start with explanation what you need to achieve.

Comment: Take a look at this question and the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452077/how-to-get-click-event-of-qlineedit-in-qt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Click Event of QLineEdit in QT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452077/how-to-get-click-event-of-qlineedit-in-qt)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such signal in Qt widgets.
You need to derive QLineEdit class and implement void QLineEdit::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e), like this:

```
class MyLineEdit public QLineEdit {
...
virtual void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e) { emit clicked(); }

signals:
void clicked();
}
```

Later, you can promote QLineEdit in graphical editor to MyLineEdit class.